# what is the correct approach to test riverpod with mockito

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, mockito, riverpod

what is the correct approach to test riverpod with mockito?

running the code above,

```dart
/// ### edited snippets from production side ###
/// not important, skip to the TEST below!

/// this seems meaningless just because it is out of context
mixin FutureDelegate<T> {
  Future<T> call();
}

/// delegate implementation

import '../../shared/delegate/future_delegate.dart';

const k_STRING_DELEGATE = StringDelegate();

class StringDelegate implements FutureDelegate<String> {
  const StringDelegate();
  @override
  Future<String> call() async {
   /// ... returns a string at some point, not important now
  }
}



/// the future provider
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import '<somewhere>/delegate.dart'; /// the code above

final stringProvider = FutureProvider<String>((ref) => k_STRING_DELEGATE());

/// ### edited snippets from TEST side ###


/// mocking the delegate
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import '<see above>/future_delegate.dart';

class MockDelegate extends Mock implements FutureDelegate<String> {}


/// actual test 
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/all.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import '<somewhere in my project>/provider.dart';
import '../../domain/<somewhere>/mock_delegate.dart'; // <= the code above

void main() {
  group('`stringProvider`', () {
    final _delegate = MockDelegate();
    test('WHEN `delegate` throws THEN `provider`return exception',
        () async {
      when(_delegate.call()).thenAnswer((_) async {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
        throw 'ops';
      });

      final container = ProviderContainer(
        overrides: [
          stringProvider
              .overrideWithProvider(FutureProvider((ref) => _delegate()))
        ],
      );
      expect(
        container.read(stringProvider),
        const AsyncValue<String>.loading(),
      );
      await Future<void>.value();
      expect(container.read(stringProvider).data.value, [isA<Exception>()]);
    });
  });
}
```

running the test returns

```sh
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'value' was called on null.
  Receiver: null
  Tried calling: value
  dart:core                                Object.noSuchMethod
  src/logic/path/provider_test.dart 28:48  main.<fn>.<fn>
```

I'm new to riverpod, clearly I'm missing something
I tried to follow [this](https://riverpod.dev/docs/cookbooks/testing/)

Comment: As a side note, if stringProvider is a mock because it is overridden, the only thing you are testing is the riverpod package itself. But maybe you just did it on purpose to demonstrate your issue.

Answer (score 4):

I found that I had some extra errors specifically when using `StateNotifierProvider`.  The trick was to not only override the StateNotifierProvider, but also its `state` property (which is a StateNotifierStateProvider object).

```dart
class SomeState {
  final bool didTheThing;
  SomeState({this.didTheThing = false});
}

class SomeStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<SomeState> {
  SomeStateNotifier() : super(SomeState());

  bool doSomething() {
    state = SomeState(didTheThing: true);
    return true;
  }
}

final someStateProvider = StateNotifierProvider<SomeStateNotifier>((ref) {
  return SomeStateNotifier();
});

class MockStateNotifier extends Mock implements SomeStateNotifier {}

void main() {
  final mockStateNotifier = MockStateNotifier();
  when(mockStateNotifier.doSomething()).thenReturn(true);

  final dummyState = SomeState(didTheThing: true); // This could also be mocked

  ProviderScope(
    overrides: [
      someStateProvider.overrideWithValue(mockStateProvider), // This covers usages like "useProvider(someStateProvider)"
      someStateProvider.state.overrideWithValue(dummyState),  // This covers usages like "useProvider(someStateProvider.state)"
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(...),
  );
}
```

Comment: I get the error `The getter 'state' isn't defined for the type 'StateNotifierProvider...`
Anyone else?

Comment: @MatthewRideout Any luck on this? :)

Comment: @HugoH yes, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011054/riverpod-testing-how-to-mock-state-with-statenotifierprovider). Mockito / mocktail are not needed to mock state for StateNotifierProvider.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 errors in your code

You're trying to test a throw error, so you should use `thenThrow` instead of `thenAnswer`, but because you're overriding a mixing method I would recommend instead of using `Mock` use `Fake` (from the same mockito library) to override methods and then throw it as you want

```
class MockDelegate extends Fake implements FutureDelegate<String> {

  @override
  Future<String> call() async {
    throw NullThrownError; //now you can throw whatever you want
  }
}
```

And the second problem (and the one your code is warning you) is that you deliberately are throwing, so you should expect an AsyncError instead, so calling `container.read(stringProvider).data.value` is an error because reading the riverpod documentation:

When calling data:

> The current data, or null if in loading/error.

so if you're expecting an error (AsyncError) data is null, and because of that calling `data.value` its the same as writing `null.value` which is the error you're experiencing

This is the code you could try:

```
class MockDelegate extends Fake implements FutureDelegate<String> {
  @override
  Future<String> call() async {
    throw NullThrownError;
  }
}

void main() {
  group('`stringProvider`', () {
    final _delegate = MockDelegate();
    test('WHEN `delegate` throws THEN `provider`return exception', () async {

      final container = ProviderContainer(
        overrides: [
          stringProvider
              .overrideWithProvider(FutureProvider((ref) => _delegate.call()))
        ],
      );

      expect(container.read(stringProvider), const AsyncValue<String>.loading());

      container.read(stringProvider).data.value;

      await Future<void>.value();
      expect(container.read(stringProvider), isA<AsyncError>()); // you're expecting to be of type AsyncError because you're throwing
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer and your code sample, although it does not use mockito 
I'd like to use mockito for the extra features like verify / verfynomoreinteractions, for now I'll follow the basic testing from the docs, maybe I'll figure it out later

Comment: I thoug you're using mockito because you already had import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart'; in your code, either way because its a fake you can create your own class that extends FutureDelegate and override with a throw, it should work without mockito

Answer (score 1):

Also consider mocking out various providers by using an Override in your top level ProviderScope.  That's what override can do quite well.

Comment: first of all thank you for taking the time for answering, I'd like to use mockito for the extra features like verify / verfynomoreinteractions, but I think you are right, I might settle with that for now, still hoping to figure out how to use both in the future